# Remove white space in templates when using ERB class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, erb

Here is a simple ERB template:

```
# /tmp/test.erb
Hello
<% if (@x) %>
XXX
<% end %>
Goodbye
```

Here is my Ruby code to render it:

```
require 'erb'
@x = false
renderer = ERB.new(File.read('/tmp/test.erb'))
output = renderer.result()
print output
```

Here is the output:

```
Hello

Goodbye
```

Note the blank line. I cannot seem to get rid of that extra whitespace. The tags `<%-` and `-%>` do not work with `ERB.new` (I get errors).

How do I get rid of the white space with
I am using Ruby 2.3.

Comment: Have you tried putting all that on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay, when you want to use the `<%- -%>` tag (this prevents the `if` output) you have to pass `-` to `trim_mode` option of `ERB.new` to use it.

See the following example:

Change you `test.erb` file to the following code:

```
Hello
<% if (@x) -%>
 XXX
<% end -%>
Goodbye
```

When you instance `ERB`, pass the option like this:

```
renderer = ERB.new(File.read('test.erb'), nil, '-')
```

Now, the `<%- -%>` tags will works fine, hope this helps!